# Flutter Delayed Animation code Error : AnimationController.forward() called after AnimationController.dispose()

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented a delayed animation in my welcome screen, but I get this below error in my flutter App. Let me know if there is an error in my code that I can correct and fix this issue.

The error is :

```
E/flutter (11565): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)]
Unhandled Exception:
'package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart': Failed
assertion: line 455 pos 7: '_ticker != null':
AnimationController.forward() called after
AnimationController.dispose()
```

Here is my code:

```dart
class DelayedAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final int delay;
 
  DelayedAnimation({@required this.child, this.delay});

  @override
  _DelayedAnimationState createState() => _DelayedAnimationState();
}

class _DelayedAnimationState extends State<DelayedAnimation> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<Offset> _animOffset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
    );
    final curve = CurvedAnimation(
      curve: Curves.decelerate,
      parent: _controller,
    );
    _animOffset = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.35),
      end: Offset.zero,
    ).animate(curve);

    if (widget.delay == null) {
      _controller.forward();
    } else {
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: widget.delay), () {
        _controller.forward();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: _animOffset,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
      opacity: _controller,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This problem will often occur when you use a `Timer` or `Future.delayed` to interact with an `AnimationController`. This is the problem. Lets say that `delay = 1000`.

The following code tells flutter that in 1000 milliseconds, call `forward()` on the animation controller in your `DelayedAnimation` widget

```
Timer(Duration(milliseconds: widget.delay), () {
   _controller.forward();
});
```

However, before this happens, your `DelayedAnimation` widget is disposed (this happens, for example, if the user moves to a different screen)

That means that when the `Timer` executes, it is calling `forward()` on a controller which has been disposed (because the `DelayedAnimation` has been disposed)

There are a few solutions.

1. Check the `mounted` property before calling forward:

```
Timer(
  Duration(
    milliseconds: widget.delay
  ), 
  () {
    if(mounted) {
      _controller.forward();
    }
  }
);
```

or 2. Store the Timer when you create it:

```
_timer = Timer(
  Duration(
    milliseconds: widget.delay
  ), 
  () {
    _controller.forward();
  }
);
```

Then cancel it on dispose:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
    _timer?.cancel();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, James Allen. This helped. My error is gone now.

Comment: @James, these are great solutions to this. Thanks for the answer. Now I know how to handle this error if it ever comes up. What I don't understand and is bothersome is - why this is happening in the first place, when the time to go to the next screen (15 seconds as set) is clearly much more than both the animation times which are set around 1100 milliseconds max. I don't see any other reason. Do you have an idea why this could be happening?

Comment: +1... If you are inside a RenderObject, the equivalent is to check the `attached` property of the RenderObject in question.

Answer (score 1):

You have not given info regarding the `Timer` which you have used, so cannot comment on what might be going wrong in your code.

But I tried using `Future.delayed` to delay the animation, and it is working fine for me.

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: widget.delay), () {
        _controller.forward();
      });
```

Hope this helps you.

*Edit:*

> '_ticker != null': AnimationController.forward() called after
> AnimationController.dispose()

The error says, `forward()` called after `dispose()`. This could happen in a case where you are going off to another screen before the delay expires and triggers `_controller.forward()`. Going off to another screen causes `_contoller.dispose()` and so calling `_controller.forward()` after that causes the error, because the `_controller` is already disposed. For example, if the app is going to next screen after 1 sec and the animation delay is 2 secs, then this could happen.

Comment: Can you give me the full code for this that you tried? I am still unable to get this fixed.

Comment: I don't think sharing the full code will help. Because it is the same code, only difference I did it with Future.delayed(). The fact that you tried with Future.delayed() and it didn't work, means the cause is somewhere else. I'll edit the answer and add to it another thing to look for, which I think could be the problem possibly. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I have posted the implementation page, let me know if there is anything wrong in it that is having the error come up.

Comment: @Jyo I tried with the exact same implementation and it is working perfectly fine with me. I even see the animation and after about 15 seconds (as set in the code), the app also transitions to the next screen with no error.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. But for some wired reason, this error is not going out from my codes. I rewrote the code completely but the error is still the same.

Comment: Not sure, but it may be possible we are using different flutter versions. Maybe that is why different behavior for both of us for the same code. Are you using latest?